# Ayuda con tipo de dato en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Este es el script de la base de datos, todo se inserta correctamente excepto la parte del `precio`, al verlo en un archivo php (en el que todos los datos están en una tabla) se presentan como :

```
31.84
38.74
```

y

```
32.51
```

es decir se omite el último número que es `0` en los tres casos, necesito poder ver las cifras como las inserté, pero no sé si es por el tipo de dato, o por un error al insertarlas.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `catalogo_audi` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `catalogo_audi`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`audi`(
  `idAudi` int,
  `modelo` varchar(30) ,
  `imagen` varchar(30) ,

  `descripcion` TEXT,
  `precio` float

)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `audi` (`idAudi`, `modelo`,`imagen`, `descripcion`, `precio`) VALUES
(1, 'Audi A4','P01.jpg','Tipo de motor: Diésel, 4 cilindros en línea, 16 válvulas, TDI con turbo TGV e intercooler, DOHC
Sistema de inyección common-rail, 1.800 bares con inyectores piezoeléctricos, inyección directa con inyectores de 8 orificios, turboalimentación VTG con refrigeración del aire de sobrealimentación; canales de admisión de turbulencia y tangenciales, canal de turbulencia regulado; Bosch EDC; regulación del caudal y del inicio de inyección, control de presión de sobrealimentación y de recircirculación de gases de escape a baja temperatura.
Velocidad máxima: 215 km/h
Aceleración: 9,5 s',31.840),
(2, 'AUDI A6','P02.jpg','Tipo de motor: 4 cilindros en línea, inyección directa TFSI - 16 válvulas
Sistema de gestión del motor totalmente electrónico. Bosch MED 9.1; inyección directa, regulación lambda adaptable, encendido con distribución estática de alta tensión, regulación de picado selectiva y adaptable.
Velocidad máxima: 228 km/h
Aceleración: 8,2 s',38.740),
(3, 'Audi A8','P03.jpg','Tipo de motor: 8 cilindros en V, 32 válvulas
Sistema de gestión del motor totalmente electrónico, Bosch MED 17.1.1; inyección directa FSI con 120 bar de presión del sistema.
Velocidad máxima: 250 km/h
Aceleración: 6,9 s',0),
(4, 'aUDI TT','P04.jpg','Tipo de motor: 4 cilindros en línea, inyección directa TFSI - 16 válvulas
Gestión electrónica con control electrónico del acelerador, inyección directa; regulación lambda adaptable; encendido con distribución estática de alta tensión, regulación de picado selectiva y adaptable por cilindro; medición de la masa de aire.
Velocidad máxima: 226 km/h
Aceleración: 7,2 s',32.510);
```

Comment: Por favor `float` no para ese tipo de valores, te va a traer muchos problemas. El mejor tipo de datos para esos propósitos es `DECIMAL`. Al definirlo le puedes indicar el número de dígitos que deberá soportar después del punto, por ejemplo: `DECIMAL (10,3)`. [Ver la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) para más detalles.

Answer (score 5):

Para guardar precios MySQL recomienda el tipo de datos `DECIMAL`.

Es lo que se puede deducir leyendo la documentación:

> Los tipos `DECIMAL` y `NUMERIC` almacenan valores de datos numéricos
>   exactos. Estos tipos se utilizan cuando es importante preservar la
>   precisión exacta, por ejemplo, con datos monetarios.
>
> MySQL almacena valores `DECIMAL` en formato binario. Vea la [Sección
>   12.21, "Matemáticas de Precisión"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math.html).
>
> En una declaración de columna `DECIMAL`, la precisión y la escala
>   pueden (y generalmente deben) especificarse; por ejemplo:
>
> ```
> salario DECIMAL (5,2)
> ```
>
> En este ejemplo, `5` es la precisión y `2` es la escala. La precisión
>   representa el número de dígitos significativos que se almacenan para
>   los valores, y la escala representa el número de dígitos que se pueden
>   almacenar después del punto decimal.
>
> El SQL estándar requiere que `DECIMAL (5,2)` pueda almacenar cualquier
>   valor con cinco dígitos y dos decimales, por lo que los valores que se
>   pueden almacenar en el rango de la columna de salario de -999.99 a
>   999.99.
>
> En SQL estándar, la sintaxis `DECIMAL (M)` es equivalente a `DECIMAL
>   (M, 0)`. De forma similar, la sintaxis `DECIMAL` es equivalente a
>   DECIMAL `(M, 0)`, donde la implementación permite decidir el valor de
>   `M`. MySQL admite ambas formas variantes de sintaxis `DECIMAL`. El
>   valor predeterminado de `M` es `10`.
>
> Si la escala es `0`, los valores `DECIMAL` no contienen punto decimal
>   o parte fraccionaria.
>
> El número máximo de dígitos para `DECIMAL` es `65`, pero el rango real
>   para una columna DECIMAL determinada puede estar restringido por la
>   precisión o escala de una columna determinada. Cuando a dicha columna
>   se le asigna un valor con más dígitos después del punto decimal que
>   los permitidos por la escala especificada, el valor se convierte a esa
>   escala. (El comportamiento preciso es específico del sistema
>   operativo, pero generalmente el efecto es el truncamiento al número
>   permitido de dígitos).
>
> <sub>[Documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html)</sub>

### Conclusión

Si es posible, cambia el tipo de datos de `float` a `decimal`, aplicando una política de seguridad y verificación de datos si la tabla en cuestión ya está en producción.

#### ¿Por qué no usar `float`?

Porque los valores `float` son vulnerables a errores de redondeo y dependen además de muchos otros factores, por lo que la exactitud está en juego.

La documentación dice lo siguiente:

> Debido a que los valores de coma flotante son aproximados y no se
>   almacenan como valores exactos, los intentos de tratarlos como exactos
>   en las comparaciones pueden generar problemas. También están sujetos a
>   dependencias de plataforma o implementación. Para obtener más
>   información, consulte la [Sección B.5.4.8, "Problemas con los valores
>   de coma flotante"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html).
>
> <sub>[`float` en la documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html)</sub>

Comment: muchas gracias por contestar! ya lo resolví!

Comment: Me alegro @ale. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Cuando sea posible consulta [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta a mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Saludos.