# Problema con números con coma en php

Tags: php

tengo almacenado en mysql este numero en un campo varchar 30,50 pero al leerlo en php de este modo `number_format($DLineasVenta["precio"],2,",",".")` donde Precio= 30,50 me quita los decimales y muestra solo 30

¿Hay alguna forma de que me muestre siempre decimales tal cual los tengo guardados en la base de datos?

Comment: Prueba a guardar el dato como tipo decimal, si vas a trabajar con decimales te sería mas conveniente

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿por qué usas `VARCHAR` para un dato `DECIMAL`, cuando MySQL tiene un tipo de dato específico para los decimales? No sólo vas a tener problemas al momento de presentarlos, sino que tus cálculos serán erróneos. ¿Por qué no declaras esa columna del tipo `DECIMAL`?

Comment: En eso estoy, pero he guardado los datos con , en vez de con puntos y si cambio ahora el campo a “float” me pierde los decimales

Comment: Eso he hecho @A.Cedano ahora estoy con el guardado de esos decimales y la conversion a formato ingles... que en españa tenemos la mania de separar millares por . y decimales por , y estoy viendo como solucionarlo para que el usuario pueda usar el formato español. de momento tengo solucionado convertir las , por . con srt_replace ahora estoy viendo lo de los .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo que no utilices un varchar para guardar numeros por que te puede pasar lo que te esta pasando ahora, pero bueno para dar respuesta a tu pregunta prueba con esto

```
 $num='20,67';
 $num=str_replace(',','.',$num);
 $num=$num+20.00;
 echo $num;
```

Comment: Estoy cambiando todo a float y cambiando las, por puntos... Por casualidad no sabras como hacer que aunque yo en el input haya puesto una coma lo convierta a un punto para guardar en mysql ¿no?

Comment: haz lo mismo utiliza la funcion str_replace para cambiar el numero que te entra con coma se lo cambias por punto y lo guardas

Comment: Lo malo de hacerlo asi es que si algún usuario me mete 100.000,32 mysql se va a volver loco... con lo que tendría que hacer dos str_replace uno para quitar los . y otro para las ,

Comment: lo puedes obligar en el js a que no te ingrese puntos para separar las milesismas y decimas

Comment: Tambien es verdad.... Mil gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No, no, y noooo. **No guardes nunca datos formateados en la base de datos**. El formato es algo que sirve para la salida, para presentar los datos. Cuando tú guardas datos formateados en una fuente de datos los limitas, le quitas su utilidad para otros usos a veces delicados, como cálculos. Por eso en programación **existen mil formas de presentar los datos**, para evitarnos guardarlos formateados. Todavía no me queda claro cómo están tus datos en la base de datos. Si están realmente en `DECIMAL` hay mejores maneras de presentarlos.

Comment: Que no lo guarde como float? @A.Cedano

Comment: @Killpe ya que has escrito: *Estoy cambiando todo a float y cambiando las, por puntos...* No, no tienes que cambiar nada a `float`. El tipo de dato específico para trabajar con valores como precios es `DECIMAL`, no `FLOAT`. Ya que `DECIMAL` es más preciso en cuestiones como redondeos, descuentos con porcentajes, etc.  [Ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130611/29967). Aunque no está aceptada, porque el OP parece que no volvió más por aquí, es útil... Y lo de cambiar las `,` por `.`  debes hacerlo a sacar los datos de la BD, no al guardarlos en ella. No sé si me explico.

Comment: Pero mysql trabaja con . Para separar decimales ¿no? Yo lo tenía guardado como varchar y con , por eso lo he cambiado todo a . @A.Cedano

Comment: Entendido @Killpe. Solamente tienes que declarar la columna del tipo `DECIMAL` y al insertar los datos usar el punto. Por ejemplo: `199.99`. Luego por programación tienes mil maneras de presentar los datos. Es más PHP tiene funciones específicas para trabajar con números, o con valores monetarios y tiene también funciones de configuración como `setlocale`. [Mira por ejemplo **`money_format`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.money-format.php) en el Manual de PHP. La cuestión aquí es que, si tus datos están guardados correctamente los puedes presentar luego de la forma que quieras.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes hacer es normalizar tus datos en la base de datos, por lo que lo primero será reemplazar las comas por puntos:

```
UPDATE tu_tabla
SET columna = REPLACE(columna, ',', '.');
```

Lo segundo será cambiar el tipo de dato de la columna a `DECIMAL`

```
ALTER TABLE tu_tabla MODIFY columna DECIMAL(10, 2);
```

Con esto ya podemos utilizar lo siguiente sin problema:

```
number_format($row["columna"], 2, ",", ".")
```

A la hora de insertar en la base de datos deberás hacerlo utilizando el punto como separador de los decimales. Si el dato viene de un input puedes aplicar `str_replace()` para para permitir al usuario utilizar la coma como te indican en la otra respuesta o utilizar ún regex para validar el dato.

Comment: Ya lo tengo todo normalizado, también cambiado a decimal 10.2 ahora me esta volviendo loco a la hora de guardar los datos que parece que lo tengo que tratar como un string o si no da fallo al guardar. pero no me guarda los decimales tampoco :(

Comment: al parecer el problema lo tengo con los . en el input muestro con number_format en formato español y claro me mete . en los millares con lo que mysql entiende que eso son decimales

Comment: @Killpe  Establece el 4 parámetro de `number_format()` como una cadena vacía si lo vas a utilizar para poner un valor predeterminado en el input

Comment: Y si el usuario pone el . separando los millares?