# MYSQL Diferencia entre FLOAT y DOUBLE

Tags: mysql

Qué diferencia existe entre campos tipo `Float` y `Double` en *MySQL*? Además de la diferencia de poder abarcar `Double` números más grandes que los que puede almacenar `Float`. Hay algunas otras diferencias?

Por ejemplo, si voy a utilizarlo para almacenar el precio de un producto y sé que mis productos siempre costaran entre 0 y 10,000, cuál me conviene usar?

Comment: Hace un tiempo, para dar respuesta a una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130609/29967) parecida a la tuya yo traduje [lo que dice la documentación de MySQL sobre el tipo de datos `DECIMAL`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130611/29967), explicando por qué conviene usarlo para campos destinados a guardar precios. Al final de la respuesta también explico por qué no usar `float`. Te dejo el enlace por si te puede ser de ayuda.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dentro de MySQL (desconozco en otros gestores)

1. Float es para presición simple en un rango de 4 bytes
2. Double es para un rango de presición de 8 bytes

Además de eso FLOAT permite una presición de 0 a 23 mientras que DOUBLE la maneja de 24 a 53

> En el caso de DOUBLE permite un ingreso de valores con signo desde
>   -1.7976931348623157E+308 hasta -2.2250738585072014E-308, 0, y sin signo desde 2.2250738585072014E-308 hasta 1.7976931348623157E+308

Como puedes notar la capacidad de almacenamiento de un dato de este tipo es gigantesca pero dependerá mucho en la realidad de las cualidades de tu hardware

> En el caso de FLOAT va desde -3.402823466E+38 hasta -1.175494351E-38
>   y sin signo desde 1.175494351E-38 hasta 3.402823466E+38

---

***ACTUALIZACIÓN***

**Sin embargo al revisar mejor la documentación propia será más óptimo usar decimal, pues solo te pide esto:
decimal(a, b) decimal(5, 2)
donde a o 5 es la longitud que va a ocupar y b o 2 es la cantidad de decimales que va a aceptar**

El detalle con DOUBLE y FLOAT es que no son guardados con certeza por la propia arquitectura de una PC, por lo tanto no guardan los valores de una manera fiable.

DECIMAL los aventaja por que los valores se almacenan como una especie de representación de cadena de caracteres lo que brinda una certeza mayor que con los datos anteriores

Puesto que lo que tratas de guardar y como bien me hizo la observación @gbianchi es cantidades de precios será mejor usar decimal

Comment: En realidad, si va a guardar un precio de un producto, ninguno de estos tipos de datos es correcto. Deberia usar un tipo decimal, con la cantidad de decimales que necesite. Estos tipos de datos sufren de perdida de precision, lo que para un valor de precio de producto es muy pero muy importante

Answer (score 2):

Si revisas el manual de *MySQL* para almacenar información de precios se recomienda el tipo ***Decimal(m,n)***.

Donde **m** es el total del campo y **n** es la cantidad de decimales.

Comment: Esta seria una respuesta ideal, pero podrias explicar el problema de los tipos que pregunta OP?