# ¿Por qué mi columna de tipo DOUBLE/FLOAT sólo almacena dos dígitos separados por un punto?

Tags: mysql, sql

Se supone que el tipo de dato `INTEGER` es para números sin punto

```
(ejemplo: 12345)
```

El tipo de dato `FLOAT` o `DOUBLE` es para números con punto

```
(ejemplo: 1.000).
```

Debido a que necesito almacenar los salarios de unos trabajadores obviamente requiero el punto ".", y por ello, el tipo de dato de mi columna "salario" es `DOUBLE` o `FLOAT`

Pero aun así no funciona; es decir:

Por ejemplo si desde mi formulario inserto el valor `"3.500"` en mi base de datos recibo `"3.5"`.

Cabe señalar que al crear la columna para "`salarios`" establecí la longitud en "`11`" sin embargo ahora que veo en "estructura de la tabla" no aparece ningún valor de longitud en mi columna "`salarios`", cosa que sí aparece en las otras de tipo `integer` y `varchar`.

Comment: Hola, veo 2 posibles opciones, o puedes guardar esos datos como `string` o puedes dar el formato que buscas a los datos cuando los muestras (creo que es la mejor opción).

Comment: Al hablar de `float` o `double`, la base de datos no almacena ni remotamente algún punto. La base de datos almacena una mantisa y un exponente. A estas alturas del partido, diría que todas lo hacen de acuerdo a las reglas del [Estándar 754 del IEEE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ieee-standard-754-floating-point-numbers/). Te lo menciono para que no confundas que se almacena con como se representa visualmente un dato. Si tu estás viendo el dato con un solo decimal, es un tema de _representación de la información_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considera en lugar de usar `FLOAT` o `DOUBLE` el uso  de `DECIMAL`, pues te tipo de dato ofrece mayor exactitud con los registros numéricos almacenados que sus contrapartes.

La estructura que tiene es:

```
DECIMAL(A, B)
```

Donde:

- `A` es la longitud máxima del número a almacenar *considerando los decimales también*
- `B` es el número de cifras que de la cantidad total en A se van a considerar para almacenar los decimales

**Ejemplo**

```
DECIMAL(10, 2)
```

> Lo anterior va a permitir almacenar un número de máximo ocho cifras antes del punto decimal y dos cifras como máximo después de dicho punto.

Los datos de tipo decimal permiten el registro máximo de 65 caracteres.

Si requieres modificar la estructura de tu columna en tu tabla puedes valerte del siguiente comando:

```
ALTER TABLE miTabla MODIFY COLUMN miColumna DECIMAL(A, B);
```

**Referencias**

- [`DECIMAL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)

Comment: Funciona! Pero aún tengo una duda sobre el punto A y B de tu lista. No está lo suficientemente claro. Quieres decir que el parámetro A es para especificar la longitud de todo lo anterior al punto, y el parámetro B es para especificar la longitud de lo posterior al punto? Disculpa pero no te entiendo bien.  Hace un rato modifiqué mi columna "salarios" manualmente, y cuando establecí la longitud "3,3" para el tipo DECIMAL me arrojó ERROR, pero cuando establecí la longitud "7,3" me aceptó y además se mostraron los valores como deben, es decir "3.000"

Comment: @user137527 A es la longitud total a almacenar y B es la cantidad que de ese total tomarás para los decimales, por eso el primero te falló y el segundo te funcionó

Comment: O sea si quiero almacenar un maximo de "100.000" tendría que poner en A longitud "7" y en B ¿que cosa?

Comment: A sería 6 y B sería 3 para indicarle de la longitud total(6), toma 3 para los decimales

Comment: Ah ya te entendí. O sea que "." no cuenta. SI puedes edita los puntos A y B de tu lista para que estén más claros y darte el check de mejor respuesta.  Y gracias.

Comment: Dame unos minutos y mejoro la explicación 

Answer (score 6):

Una tema es el dato y otro es la representación del mismo. Si revisas [la diferencia entre `FLOAT` y `DOUBLE`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164139/mysql-diferencia-entre-float-y-double) verás que ambos permiten almacenar números decimales con distinta precisión, pero ambos llegan más lejos de los tres decimales que esperas. Como los muestres luego esto números, nada tiene que ver con los datos, suele ser más bien un tema de aplicación o del cliente que estas usando para conectarte y hacer la consulta, lo habitual es que se descarten los ceros no significativos.

Insertar en una columna `FLOAT` o `DOUBLE` un valor `3.500` no deja de ser una representación de `3.5` o eventualmente de `3.5000000`. Otra cosa es el valor `3.501` que efectivamente debiera mostrarse como `3.501`.

Si quieres estándarizar una salida numérica, puedes usar `format(numero, precisión)`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(3.5, 3);
```

Por otro lado, adhiero a la respuesta de @Aprendiz, los tipos `DECIMAL()` ofrecen una mejor alternativa en muchas aplicaciones dónde se suele trabajar con cantidades fijas de decimales.

Comment: Buena respuesta, entonces para comprender mejor, ¿el puede seguir usando dichos tipos de datos, sin embargo para representación deberá usar por ejemplo `FORMAT` para indicar la salida esperada?

Comment: Me estás diciendo que en realidad si estoy almacenando "3.500" solo que lo que la DB muestra es una abreviación (ejemplo "3.5")?? O he entendido mal?

Comment: @Aprendiz, puede seguir usando estos tipos de datos, la representación del dato la puede hacer una aplicación, o la puede retornar el servidor como cadena un `FORMAT`

Comment: @user137527, digamos que sí, aunque para ser más exactos, un float o double no guardan "3.5" o "3.500",  fijate el comentario que te dejó jachguate, el punto es una convención que se usa cuando se representa el número.