# Evitar Redondeo Automatico en SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Cuento realizo un insert a una tabla de mi base de datos los valores los redondea y quiero evitar eso, necesito que los valores sean guardados como son digitados , las columnas en esta de tipo float(18,2).
y el valor desde php lo paso por la funcion bcdiv para evitar rendondeo... que no estoy tomando en cuenta gracias

```
$datos = array("Rnc_Empresa_LD" => $Rnc_Empresa_606,
                "id_registro" => $id_registro606,
                "Rnc_Factura" => $Rnc_Factura_606,
                "NCF" => $NCF_606,
                "Nombre_Empresa" => $_POST["Nombre_Suplidor"],
                "NAsiento" => $_POST["NAsiento"],
                "id_grupo" => $idgrupo,
                "id_categoria" => $idcategoria,
                "id_generica" => $idgenerica,
                "id_cuenta" => $idcuenta,
                "Nombre_Cuenta" => $nombrecuenta,
                "Fecha_AnoMes_LD" => $_POST["FechaFacturames_606"],
                "Fecha_dia_LD" => $_POST["FechaFacturadia_606"],
                "id_Proyecto" => $idproyecto,
                "CodigoProyecto" => $codproyecto,
                "debito" => $debito,
                "credito" => $credito,
                "ObservacionesLD" => $ObservacionesLD,
                "Extraer_NAsiento" => $Extraer_NAsiento,
                "Tipo_Transaccion" => $Transaccion_606,
                "Fecha_AnoMes_Trans" => $_POST["FechaFacturames_606"],
                "Fecha_dia_Trans" => $_POST["FechaFacturadia_606"],
                "id_banco" => $id_banco,
                "referencia" => $_POST["Descripcion"],
                "Usuario_Creador" => $_POST["UsuarioLogueado"],
                "Accion" => $Accion);
```

$respuesta = ModeloDiario::mdllibrodiario($tabla, $datos);

static public function mdllibrodiario($tabla, $datos){

```
$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(Rnc_Empresa_LD, id_registro, Rnc_Factura, NCF, Nombre_Empresa, NAsiento, id_grupo, id_categoria, id_generica, id_cuenta, Nombre_Cuenta, Fecha_AnoMes_LD, Fecha_dia_LD, id_Proyecto, CodigoProyecto, debito, credito, ObservacionesLD, Extraer_NAsiento, Tipo_Transaccion, Fecha_AnoMes_Trans, Fecha_dia_Trans, id_banco, referencia, Usuario_Creador, Accion) VALUES (:Rnc_Empresa_LD, :id_registro, :Rnc_Factura, :NCF, :Nombre_Empresa, :NAsiento, :id_grupo, :id_categoria, :id_generica, :id_cuenta, :Nombre_Cuenta, :Fecha_AnoMes_LD, :Fecha_dia_LD, :id_Proyecto, :CodigoProyecto, :debito, :credito, :ObservacionesLD, :Extraer_NAsiento, :Tipo_Transaccion, :Fecha_AnoMes_Trans, :Fecha_dia_Trans, :id_banco, :referencia, :Usuario_Creador, :Accion)");

$stmt ->bindParam(":Rnc_Empresa_LD", $datos["Rnc_Empresa_LD"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":id_registro", $datos["id_registro"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":Rnc_Factura", $datos["Rnc_Factura"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":NCF", $datos["NCF"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":Nombre_Empresa", $datos["Nombre_Empresa"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":NAsiento", $datos["NAsiento"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":id_grupo", $datos["id_grupo"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt ->bindParam(":id_categoria", $datos["id_categoria"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt ->bindParam(":id_generica", $datos["id_generica"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":id_cuenta", $datos["id_cuenta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":Nombre_Cuenta", $datos["Nombre_Cuenta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":Fecha_AnoMes_LD", $datos["Fecha_AnoMes_LD"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":Fecha_dia_LD", $datos["Fecha_dia_LD"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":id_Proyecto", $datos["id_Proyecto"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":CodigoProyecto", $datos["CodigoProyecto"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":debito", $datos["debito"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":credito", $datos["credito"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":ObservacionesLD", $datos["ObservacionesLD"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":Extraer_NAsiento", $datos["Extraer_NAsiento"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":Tipo_Transaccion", $datos["Tipo_Transaccion"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt ->bindParam(":Fecha_AnoMes_Trans", $datos["Fecha_AnoMes_Trans"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":Fecha_dia_Trans", $datos["Fecha_dia_Trans"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":id_banco", $datos["id_banco"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":referencia", $datos["referencia"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":Usuario_Creador", $datos["Usuario_Creador"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(":Accion", $datos["Accion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);


    if($stmt->execute()){
        return "ok";

    }else{

        return "error";

    }

    $stmt -> close();
    $stmt = null;
```

}/* CIERRE funcion*/

Comment: Haz un `var_dump()` de los datos antes de guardar, para saber si el problema viene desde ahí.

Comment: si lo he hecho el cambio se da es en sql cuando se guarda yo no se si es algo que debo poner en los PDO los valores que me cambia es el de Debito y Credito

Comment: Probablemente convendría cambiar el tipo a DECIMAL, revisa las respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164139/mysql-diferencia-entre-float-y-double)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Ayuda con tipo de dato en MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130609/ayuda-con-tipo-de-dato-en-mysql)

Comment: creo el problema estaba en declarar como tipo float(18,2) en la tabla, gracias