# ¿Como consultar ultimo registro de una tabla MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Hola buenas noches estimados amigos informáticos, tengo un problema y estaría muy agradecido que me dieran una mano. 
El planteamiento es el siguiente:
Yo tengo una tabla llamada PAGAR, y en la tabla PAGAR se insertan varios registros con usuario y quisiera poder consultar el último insert de ese usuario. Por ejemplo:

```
TABLA: PAGO

id_pag INT Autoincrement
id_clie VARCHAR (50)
fecha DATE
descripcion VARCHAR(100)
debe DOUBLE 4,2
abono DOUBLE 4,2
saldo DOUBLE 4,2
saldoacum DOUBLE 4,2
```

Con esta estructura de tabla Yo tengo los siguientes datos insertados:

```
id_pag       id_clie       fecha      descripcion    debe    abono    saldo  saldoacum



1           JUAN PEREZ     2019-02-26       ESPAGO    5.00    7.00     7.00       6.20
2           JUAN PEREZ     2019-02-27       ESPAGO    8.00    9.00     10.00      7.50
3           JUAN PEREZ     2019-02-28       ESPAGO    16.00   15.00    5.50       5.60
4           PEDRO ROBERTO  2019-03-01       ESPAGO    6.50    8.90     6.30       6.30
5           PEDRO ROBERTO  2019-03-02       ESPAGO    35.00   40.00     5.50      9.60
6           JUAN PEREZ     2019-03-05       ESPAGO    25.00   25.00    25.00       25.00
```

Con el ejemplo anterior, mi pregunta sería, ¿como puedo obtener los registros correspondientes a la fila del ultimo insert por usuario? Quedando de la siguiente manera como resultado esperado:

```
6           JUAN PEREZ     2019-03-05       ESPAGO    25.00   25.00    25.00       25.00
5           PEDRO ROBERTO  2019-03-02       ESPAGO    35.00   40.00     5.50      9.60
```

Estaría más que agradecido con todos por la ayuda que me puedan brindar, he intentado un sin fin de consultas y no lo he logrado superar, quiza me falte un poco mas sobre bases de datos sin embargo hago mi esfuerzo antes de acudir a la comunidad por una mano. Muchas gracias a todos por tomarse su tiempo y gracias por compartir su conocimiento con todos! Saludos!

Comment: Puedes intentar algo como esto: **`SELECT MAX(id_dato) id_dato, usuario_id  FROM PAGAR GROUP BY usuario_id`** si te interesan las columnas `pagar` y `abonar` lo mejor será hacerlo con una sub-consulta.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por su ayuda, quiero comentarle que al aplicar esa query, el unico dato que me dá como "ultimo" es solamente el (id_dato) mas no los demas datos correspondientes a ese id_dato. Es decir, me da el siguiente resultado:
id_dato          usuario_id              pagar            abonar
3           JUAN PEREZ                  5.00             7.00
5           PEDRO ROBERTO          6.50             8.90

Donde el id_dato y usuario_id los muestra bien, pero pagar y abonar los muestra con los datos de los siguientes id_pagos: id 1 y id 4
Gracias!!

Comment: @Christian simplemente agrega los campos que faltan a la query, eso es todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado  que  quieres traer también el valor de las otras columnas, puedes hacerlo con una consulta correlativa, del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM PAGAR a 
WHERE id_dato = 
        (SELECT MAX(id_dato) FROM PAGAR b WHERE a.usuario_id=b.usuario_id) 
ORDER BY usuario_id;
```

O bien puedes hacer esto:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM PAGAR a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT usuario_id, MAX(id_dato) id_dato
        FROM PAGAR
        GROUP BY usuario_id
    ) b ON  a.id_dato = b.id_dato
ORDER BY a.usuario_id;
```

En ambos casos el resultado será el esperado.

---

#### Fiddle

Aquí puedes ver una <kbd>**[`DEMOSTRACIÓN`](https://rextester.com/VKE73227)**</kbd> sobre datos reales y hacer pruebas.

---

> #### Recomendación
>
> Para datos monetarios yo usaría `DECIMAL` en lugar de `DOUBLE`, ya que
>   este último presenta a veces problemas de precisión. Para más detalles, [consultar lo dicho en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130611/29967).

Comment: Excelente, voy a realizar pruebas y yo confirmo! Muchisimas gracias por tomarse su tiempo , se lo agradezco, ya confirmare! saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tratas de hacer es un poco complejo, mas no imposible. Esta es la solucion a tu duda, si la quieres implementar solo fijate de adecuar los nombres de las tablas y campos.

### EDITADO

```
SELECT dato1.*
FROM pagar dato1
LEFT OUTER JOIN pagar dato2
ON (dato1.id_clie = dato2.id_clie and dato1.fecha < dato2.fecha)
WHERE dato2.id_clie IS NULL
ORDER BY id_clie;
```

Así se comparan por las fechas, lo cual daría una respuesta mas asertiva a "el ultimo registro insertado por usuario".

#### Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ef16/2

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uWq6UZqBr2zQ6fuz99F4Lo/0

Nota: En mi opinión, sería más viable que manejaras [timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), ya que es más especifico a la hora de almacenar en que momento del tiempo se ingresó el registro. Y así te evitas problemas de registros con fecha similar.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, pero aun no logro armarla, el ejemplo anterior fue de una tabla que había hecho para pruebas y aun asi no la logro. La tabla que quisiera que hiciera lo que su respuesta me dió tiene mas campos. ¿como pudiera agregarle los demas campos a la consulta? Gracias

Comment: De la situacion que planteaste deduje que buscabas el campo "abonar" mas alto por cada usuario. Si me brindas la situacion completa con todos los campos que necesitas y como, con gusto te ayudo.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta con los datos de la tabla que quiero aplicarle el ejercicio mi estimado, le agradezca grandemente su ayuda.

Comment: Solo como aclaración porque aun no me queda muy claro, ¿Que campo es el que deseas comparar como máximo? ¿"saldoacum"? De lo contrario, para manejarlo de forma apropiada como "ultimo registro insertado" es muy diferente.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando comparo con otro, solo me devuelve el maximo de la columna. Por ejemplo max(id_clie) . Cuando pongo eso, me devuelve si el maximo, pero los demas datos me los devuelve como el primer registro. Yo quisiera como lo hizo anteriormente, que me extraiga todos los datos de la ultima insercion por cliente. Todos los datos de Juan y Roberto en la ultima insersion. Comparelos como usted guste compañero. Tan solo que me muestre los datos del ultimo insert de cada usuario estoy mas que contento para seguir yo con el aprendizaje. Gracias

Comment: De las 4 inserciones correspondientes a JUAN, me gustaria por medio de la consulta obtener todos los datos de la ultima insercion. Y de las 2 inserciones de PEDRO obtener la ultima.

Comment: He editado. Creo que eso resuelve tu pregunta de forma escalable. De lo contrario, notifícame para ver que falta.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias pruebo las respuestas y los hago saber! Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo estimado!

Answer (score 1):

No has pensando usar la funcion :   **LAST_INSERT_ID**

ejecutas este  comando dentro de la tabla:

> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

y te debe devolver tu ultimo registro en la tabla.

[fuente](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-last_insert_id.aspx)