Obtener el ultimo registro de una tabla mysql
Tabla: detalle_compras



fecha
id_producto
costo




05/12/2024
2
5.00


05/12/2024
3
5.00


05/12/2024
4
5.00


10/12/2024
3
4.00


10/12/2024
4
4.00


20/12/2024
3
3.00



Quisiera obtener el ultimo costo del producto según la ultima compra realizada: para obtener lo siguiente:



fecha
id_producto
costo




05/12/2024
2
5.00


20/12/2024
3
3.00


10/12/2024
4
4.00




Bienvenido al sitio, que has tratado o investigado? revisar [ask]

agrega mas contexto a tu pregunta, como un framework en espesifico como laravel, o un script en espesifico, que es lo que te falta como conectarse a la base de datos, o como hacer consultas desde php, o quieres un script sql para obtener esos datos.

Mysql o maria?? esta query es simple y esta explicada por miles de lados.. intentaste algo??

@CristhianJavierUlloaCarmona solo el script mysql para obtener los datos

@gbianchi si ya lo has hecho podrías compartir el script.

Tomando esta pregunta relacionada del gran Cedano: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/237173/131662
Puedes hacerlo con una consulta correlativa
SELECT 
    fecha,
    id_producto,
    costo
FROM detalle_compras dc1
WHERE fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha) 
               FROM detalle_compras dc2 
               WHERE dc2.id_producto = dc1.id_producto)
ORDER BY id_producto

O bien puedes hacer un INNER JOIN
SELECT 
    dc.fecha,
    dc.id_producto,
    dc.costo
FROM detalle_compras dc
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id_producto,
        MAX(fecha) AS ultima_fecha
    FROM detalle_compras
    GROUP BY id_producto
) ultimos ON dc.id_producto = ultimos.id_producto AND dc.fecha = ultimos.ultima_fecha
ORDER BY id_producto

Siempre trata de buscar el problema en las preguntas relacionadas o sugeridas por el sistema primero. Acá literalmente, tienes la respuesta hecha solo que con otros nombres de variables.
Ahora, cual de las dos es mejor? Depende del tamaño de la tabla la verdad. La consulta correlativa sería mala para tablas muy grandes, pero es fácil de entender y aplicar. Meintras que el JOIN serviría mejor para tablas grandes y bien indexadas

Este es un problema clásico de SQL, el problema es que no existen funciones para manejar series de tiempo. En una TSDB esto se resuelve en una sola línea
A mí me gusta esta manera:
WITH datos_ordenados AS (
    SELECT 
        id_producto,
        costo,
        fecha,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_producto ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        historial_precios
)
SELECT *
FROM datos_ordenados
WHERE rn = 1;

¿Por qué?
Porque pueden darse casos extremos que son difíciles de controlar usando las "respuestas clásicas". Por ejemplo: ¿Que pasaría se tenemos un dato con fecha repetida?, digamos que a los datos de ejemplos le agregamos un nuevo registro:

Fecha: 2024-12-20
id: 3
costo: 10

Este registro está repetido (en fecha e id) con el último registro de los datos de ejemplo (el que tiene costo 3) y lo que pasa es lo siguiente:
Schema (MySQL v8)
CREATE TABLE historial_precios (
    fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    id_producto INT NOT NULL,
    costo DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO historial_precios (fecha, id_producto, costo) VALUES
('2024-12-05', 2, 5.00),
('2024-12-05', 3, 5.00),
('2024-12-20', 3, 10.00), --DATO REPETIDO
('2024-12-05', 4, 5.00),
('2024-12-10', 3, 4.00),
('2024-12-10', 4, 4.00),
('2024-12-20', 3, 3.00);


Query #1
-- Usando ROW_NUMBER()
WITH datos_ordenados AS (
    SELECT 
        id_producto,
        costo,
        fecha,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_producto ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        historial_precios
)
SELECT *
FROM datos_ordenados
WHERE rn = 1;




id_producto
costo
fecha
rn




2
5.00
2024-12-05
1


3
10.00
2024-12-20
1


4
4.00
2024-12-10
1




Query #2
-- Usando Where a la fecha máxima
SELECT 
    fecha,
    id_producto,
    costo
FROM historial_precios dc1
WHERE fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha) 
               FROM historial_precios dc2 
               WHERE dc2.id_producto = dc1.id_producto)
ORDER BY id_producto;




fecha
id_producto
costo




2024-12-05
2
5.00


2024-12-20
3
10.00


2024-12-20
3
3.00


2024-12-10
4
4.00




Query #3
-- Usando Join y agrupando
SELECT 
    dc.fecha,
    dc.id_producto,
    dc.costo
FROM historial_precios dc
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id_producto,
        MAX(fecha) AS ultima_fecha
    FROM historial_precios
    GROUP BY id_producto
) ultimos ON dc.id_producto = ultimos.id_producto AND dc.fecha = ultimos.ultima_fecha
ORDER BY id_producto




fecha
id_producto
costo




2024-12-05
2
5.00


2024-12-20
3
10.00


2024-12-20
3
3.00


2024-12-10
4
4.00




View on DB Fiddle
Con el método del ROW_NUMBER() sigue mostrando 3 registros, en cambio con los métodos del "Where a la fecha máxima" y el "join+group" muestran 4 registros.
Y si quisieras que cuando el día y la id se repitan, el costo sea el promedio de ese día (que sería algo lógico), es bastante fácil acomodar la consulta para ello:
WITH datos_ordenados AS (
    SELECT 
        id_producto,
        AVG(costo),
        fecha,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_producto ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        historial_precios
    GROUP BY
        fecha,  id_producto
)
SELECT *
FROM datos_ordenados
WHERE rn = 1;

