# Error tipo de dato mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Amigos estoy comenzando en mysql, y me surgio la siguiente pregunta:

cual seria la mejor forma de poner el tipo de dato a el valor "salario"?, es este momento está en decimal. pero me genera el error de la imagen.

```
insert into personal (Nombre, Género, Edad, Area, salario) 
values ('ANDREA', 'F', '30', 'VENTAS', '1,401.00');
```

> Error Code: 1366. Incorrect decimal value: '1,401.00' for column
>   'Salario' at row 1

Comment: Colocalo sin la coma "insert into personal (Nombre, Género, Edad, Area, salario) 
values ('ANDREA', 'F', '30', 'VENTAS', '1401.00');", luego puedes agregar la coma al mostrar el dato.

Comment: `DECIMAL` es el mejor tipo de dato para un salario ([ver aquí por qué](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130611/29967)). Prueba a mandarlo así: `1401.00` El separador de miles es algo de formato, la BD lo guarda sin separador.

Comment: Otra cosa, no hacen falta las comillas: **`insert into personal (Nombre, Género, Edad, Area, salario) 
values ('ANDREA', 'F', '30', 'VENTAS', 1401.00);`**

Answer (score 2):

El error es generado debido a la coma que usas como separador de miles.

Es **muy importante** tener en cuenta que en este caso la coma es algo propio del formato y por tanto muy relativo. Por ejemplo, en algunos países el separador de miles es el punto. Por eso, siempre que trabajes con datos numéricos, fechas, etc, evita introducirlos formateados. El formato se le da a esos datos en la salida, cuando los has recuperado de la base de datos. Guardar datos formateados es un error gravísimo que puede conducir a situaciones complicadas como errores de cálculo, de comparaciones, etc.

Además, para valores decimales es recomendable que los pongas sin comillas simples, pues el manejador fuerza una conversión del dato, haciéndolo trabajar más. En inserciones masivas esto tendría efectos negativos sobre el rendimiento.

En conclusión, la forma más idónea de escribir tu consulta sería esta:

```
insert into personal (Nombre, Género, Edad, Area, salario) 
values ('ANDREA', 'F', '30', 'VENTAS', 1401.00);
```

En cuanto a tu duda sobre qué tipo de dato es mejor para un salario, no lo dudes un segundo, el mejor tipo de dato para esto es `DECIMAL`. Para entender el motivo de esto, puedes consultar [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130611/29967) a la pregunta *[Ayuda con tipo de dato en MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130609/29967)*.