# me manda error de sintaxys

Tags: mysql

Error:

## 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca ') NOT NULL , `CAN_REC_ALB` INT(6) NOT NULL , `REC` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL , `CNC' en la linea 1

còdigo:

CREATE TABLE `egallego_Gestion`.`COM_PED_LIN_G` ( `ID` INT(3) NOT NULL , `COM_PED` INT(3) NOT NULL , `NUM_LIN` INT(2) NOT NULL , `FCH` DATE NOT NULL , `FCH_REC` DATE NOT NULL , `EMP` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL , `PRV` INT(3) NOT NULL , `SER` INT(1) NOT NULL , `ALM` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL , `EXS` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL , `ART` INT(3) NOT NULL , `ART_PRV` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL , `REF_PRV` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL , `DSC` TEXT NOT NULL , `DSC_EDT` VARCHAR(0) NOT NULL , `CAN_PED` INT(6) NOT NULL , `CAN_REC` INT(6) NOT NULL , `CAN_PDT` DOUBLE(0) NOT NULL , `CAN_REC_ALB` INT(6) NOT NULL , `REC` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL , `CNC` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL , `EST` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL , `PRE` INT(6) NOT NULL , `POR_DTO` INT(2) NOT NULL , `PRE_CTE` INT(6) NOT NULL , `PRE_COSTE` INT(6) NOT NULL , `IMP` INT(6) NOT NULL , `IMP_PDT` INT(6) NOT NULL , `REG_IVA_COM` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL , `APL_RET_ALQ` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL , `APL_RET_IRP` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL , `ANT` INT(0) NOT NULL , `SIG` INT(0) NOT NULL , `ALT_USR` INT(2) NOT NULL , `MOD_USR` INT(2) NOT NULL , `ALT_TIM` TIME(4) NOT NULL , `MOD_TIM` TIME(4) NOT NULL , `OFF` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL , `OFF_USR` INT(2) NOT NULL , `OFF_TIM` TIME(4) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

quien me puede ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Si defines un campo [DOUBLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html), debes definir su precision, **por lo tanto esto es incorrecto**:

```
CAN_PDT DOUBLE(0) NOT NULL
```

De acuerdo a la documentación:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Debes definir la precisiòn, ejemplo:

```
CAN_PDT DOUBLE(2, 0) NOT NULL
```

o simplemente definir:

```
  CAN_PDT DOUBLE NOT NULL
```

Puedes cambiar tu query de esta forma:

```
CREATE TABLE egallego_Gestion.COM_PED_LIN_G (
  ID INT(3) NOT NULL,
  COM_PED INT(3) NOT NULL,
  NUM_LIN INT(2) NOT NULL,
  FCH DATE NOT NULL,
  FCH_REC DATE NOT NULL,
  EMP VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  PRV INT(3) NOT NULL,
  SER INT(1) NOT NULL,
  ALM VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  EXS VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  ART INT(3) NOT NULL,
  ART_PRV VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  REF_PRV VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  DSC TEXT NOT NULL,
  DSC_EDT VARCHAR(0) NOT NULL,
  CAN_PED INT(6) NOT NULL,
  CAN_REC INT(6) NOT NULL,
  CAN_PDT DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  CAN_REC_ALB INT(6) NOT NULL,
  REC TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  CNC TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  EST VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRE INT(6) NOT NULL,
  POR_DTO INT(2) NOT NULL,
  PRE_CTE INT(6) NOT NULL,
  PRE_COSTE INT(6) NOT NULL,
  IMP INT(6) NOT NULL,
  IMP_PDT INT(6) NOT NULL,
  REG_IVA_COM VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  APL_RET_ALQ TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  APL_RET_IRP TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  ANT INT(0) NOT NULL,
  SIG INT(0) NOT NULL,
  ALT_USR INT(2) NOT NULL,
  MOD_USR INT(2) NOT NULL,
  ALT_TIM TIME(4) NOT NULL,
  MOD_TIM TIME(4) NOT NULL,
  OFF TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  OFF_USR INT(2) NOT NULL,
  OFF_TIM TIME(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es debido a esto:

```
CAN_PDT DOUBLE(0) NOT NULL ,
```

Si revisas el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html), verás que para el tipo `DOUBLE` la sintaxis de declaración es la siguiente:

```
DOUBLE(M,D)
```

Aunque el Manual pone esta nota:

> As of MySQL 8.0.17, the nonstandard FLOAT(M,D) and DOUBLE(M,D) syntax
>   is deprecated and support for it will be removed in a future MySQL
>   version.

Esa sintaxis es obsoleta y será  removida en un futuro.

Considera usar en esa columna el tipo de dato más adecuado. Por ejemplo, si es para guardar valores monetarios es mejor usar `DECIMAL`<sup>1</sup>.

Respetando lo que quieres hacer, el código funcionaría así:

```
CREATE TABLE egallego_Gestion.COM_PED_LIN_G ( 
    ID INT(3) NOT NULL , 
    COM_PED INT(3) NOT NULL , 
    NUM_LIN INT(2) NOT NULL , 
    FCH DATE NOT NULL , 
    FCH_REC DATE NOT NULL , 
    EMP VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL , 
    PRV INT(3) NOT NULL , 
    SER INT(1) NOT NULL , 
    ALM VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL , 
    EXS VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL , 
    ART INT(3) NOT NULL , 
    ART_PRV VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL , 
    REF_PRV VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL , 
    DSC TEXT NOT NULL , 
    DSC_EDT VARCHAR(0) NOT NULL , 
    CAN_PED INT(6) NOT NULL , 
    CAN_REC INT(6) NOT NULL , 
    CAN_PDT DOUBLE(40,2) NOT NULL , 
    CAN_REC_ALB INT(6) NOT NULL , 
    REC TINYINT(1) NOT NULL , 
    CNC TINYINT(1) NOT NULL , 
    EST VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL , 
    PRE INT(6) NOT NULL , 
    POR_DTO INT(2) NOT NULL , 
    PRE_CTE INT(6) NOT NULL , 
    PRE_COSTE INT(6) NOT NULL , 
    IMP INT(6) NOT NULL , 
    IMP_PDT INT(6) NOT NULL , 
    REG_IVA_COM VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL , 
    APL_RET_ALQ TINYINT(1) NOT NULL , 
    APL_RET_IRP TINYINT(1) NOT NULL , 
    ANT INT(0) NOT NULL , 
    SIG INT(0) NOT NULL , 
    ALT_USR INT(2) NOT NULL , 
    MOD_USR INT(2) NOT NULL , 
    ALT_TIM TIME(4) NOT NULL , 
    MOD_TIM TIME(4) NOT NULL , 
    OFF TINYINT(1) NOT NULL , 
    OFF_USR INT(2) NOT NULL , 
    OFF_TIM TIME(4) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Al declarar la columna así: `DOUBLE(40,2)` se indica que tendrá un máximo de `40` dígitos y `2` posiciones después del punto decimal.

---

## Notas

1. Uno de los problemas de `DOUBLE` y de `FLOAT` es que en ciertos escenarios arrojan valores erróneos debido a la precisión en los redondeos. Para más detalles sobre esto puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130611/29967) que incluye documentación del Manual de Referencia sobre este tema.