# Insertar decimal 0 (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando insertar a la base de datos (MySQL) valores con decimal por ejemplo **43.50** pero no me está respetando insertar el 0 de la derecha y se inserta como **43.5** ,  al intentar editar directamente desde la BD sigue mostrandose 43.5, estoy declarando la variable cómo float.

Podrían apoyarme a indicarme cómo podría insertar el decimal 0?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué declaraste la columna `FLOAT` y no como `DECIMAL`? En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130611/29967) se explican algunos motivos por los que no conviene usar float para ciertos tipos de valores, como valores monetarios.

Comment: Es claro que, independiente de la representación (la máscara), el dato almacenado es el mismo? Es decir, ese cero *está ahí* (teniendo en cuenta la advertencia de @A.Cedano eso sí). Muy posiblemente ese no es tu problema (operar sobre ese monto va a dar el valor esperado, etc.) así que... cuál es tu problema con que salga .5 y no .50?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy de acuerdo con A. Cedano y Alfabravo. Pero aquí tienes una posible solución a lo que preguntas

define en tu tabla el atributo como FLOAT(**e**,**d**) donde **e** es la parte entera y **d** la parte decimal, podría ser algo así FLOAT(5,2) y cuando almacenes datos se guardarán de la siguiente manera:

345.45, 201.50, 1.20, etc

espero te sirva mi respuesta