# Obtener precio original y precio actual con una subquery en MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, subconsultas, orderby

Tengo una tabla de **anuncios** y otra de **precios**, relativa a dichos anuncios. Cuando el usuario modifica un precio en la aplicación, se agrega una nueva fila a la tabla precios, que incluye tanto el precio como la fecha en la que se modificó dicho precio.

Necesito **obtener** un listado con todos los anuncios y, de cada anuncio, **el primer precio** que se registró, **y también el último**. Para ello he recurrido a una doble subquery sobre la misma tabla de precios.

### Tablas

#### `anuncios`

| id `int` | anuncio_titulo `varchar` |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Patatas |
| 2 | Melones |

#### `precios`

| id `int` | precio `float` | precio_fecha `timestamp` | anuncios_id `int` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2021-02-16 21:12:36 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 2021-02-17 21:12:48 | 1 |
| 3 | 1000 | 2021-02-17 21:20:40 | 2 |
| 4 | 900 | 2021-02-18 13:20:49 | 2 |
| 5 | 700 | 2021-02-18 13:20:49 | 2 |

### Query

```sql
    SELECT anuncios.anuncio_titulo, precios_primeros.precio AS precio_primero, precios_actuales.precio AS precio_actual
    FROM anuncios
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM precios
        GROUP BY id
        ORDER BY precio_fecha ASC
    ) precios_primeros ON precios_primeros.anuncios_id = anuncios.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM precios
        GROUP BY id
        ORDER BY precio_fecha DESC
    ) precios_actuales ON precios_actuales.anuncios_id = anuncios.id
    GROUP BY anuncios.id
```

Esta consulta devuelve lo siguiente en mi **servidor local** (XAMPP):

| anuncio_titulo | precio_primero | precio_actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Patatas | 50 | 5 |
| Melones | 1000 | 700 |

Como podéis observar **el resultado de la consulta es correcto** **PERO** cuando se ejecuta en un servidor de un proveedor externo (lo he probado en 1&1 IONOS y en Arsys) los resultados varían prácticamente con cada ejecución. Hay veces que aparecen los precios ordenados al revés, hay veces que sale el mismo precio en las dos columnas...

## ¿Qué necesito?

Necesito entender si el problema radica en la configuración de los servidores de estos proveedores o si he hecho algo mal en la query.

También estoy abierto a ideas que podáis aportar para conseguir estos precios (primero y actual) de otra manera, aunque sea con otra estructura en la base de datos.

Gracias a todos :)

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas simplemente `SELECT MIN(precio_fecha) AS minus, MAX(precio_fecha) AS maximus FROM ...`  En ese caso los `ORDER BY` no son necesarios... Y, me parece que no necesitas tampoco los `JOIN` ni las sub-consultas, ¿qué datos necesitas exactamente? Otro error que veo es usar `float` para tipo de dato monetario. `float` tiene muchos errores de precisión, deberías usar `decimal` (consulta [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130611/29967) para más detalles).

Comment: @A.Cedano mysql y sus problemas con los groups by... ;)

Comment: Sí @gbianchi. Me parece que en las últimas versiones se van acercando al estándar en ese sentido.

Comment: Igual aparte del tema del group by, tiene que hacer lo que dijiste, y luego traer los registros de la tabla que se joinean con ellos... viene por ese lado.. y arreglar lo de decimal... hay una respuesta que va a llevar un rato...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!