# como evitar que mysql interprete el punto como un decimal

Tags: mysql, sql

quiero meter este dato en una base de datos mysql: 114.239, pero solo me mete 114. El tipo de datos esta definido como un int. El numero en cuestion no es decimal simplemente son 114 mil 239. Al sacar los datos de otra pagina web que vienen en este formato me resulta muy incomodo andar quitandole  el punto. Me vendria bien saber un metodo para que no interprete el punto como decimal.
un saludo.

Comment: Ha probado a ponerlo en float? Y en vez de usar un . usar una ,?

Comment: El error aquí es precisamente **querer reflejar el formato en los datos que estás guardando**. El formato es algo circunstancial, por tanto debes reflejarlo en el contexto, no en la realidad misma de los datos. Como podrás entender, en algunos lugares el separador de miles es el punto y en otros es la coma. Si tú decides guardar el dato con un separador, aparte de que tendrás que forzar un cambio del tipo de dato, luego tendrás que vértelas si el contexto cambia. Guarda el dato tal cual: `114239` y formatea en la salida.

Comment: Y ni hablar de como implementar búsquedas en un formato de datos desconocido o incompatible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error aquí es precisamente **querer reflejar el formato en los datos que estás guardando**.

El formato es algo **circunstancial**, por tanto debes reflejarlo en el contexto, no en la realidad misma de los datos. Como podrás entender, en algunos lugares el separador de miles es el punto y en otros es la coma. Si tú decides guardar el dato con un separador, aparte de que tendrás que forzar un cambio del tipo de dato, luego tendrás que vértelas si el contexto cambia.

Guarda el dato tal cual: `114239` y formatea en la salida. Aquí lo más importante es que elijas el tipo de dato adecuado para esa columna. Por ejemplo, si esa columna va a representar un precio o un valor monetario, [lo propio es que la declares como `DECIMAL`, sobre todo para las posibles fracciones y para evitar errores de redondeo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130611/29967).

Sea como sea, si ese número debe ser `INT` o `DECIMAL` será muy fácil formatear en la salida, que es donde correspende.

Veamos un ejemplo donde tu número es guardado así, sin más: `114239`

Ahora, si te piden un reporte donde en una columna se presenten los datos para Alemania, y en otra columna para los EEUU, con esto lo resuelves:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(114239,0,'de_DE') AS de, 
    FORMAT(114239,0,'en_US') AS us;
```

Salida:

```
   de           us
----------------------
114.239       114,239
```

Creo que con este ejemplo contextual se entiende la importancia de **respetar la realidad de los datos al momento de declararlos y de guardalos**. Si no respestas eso, te pasarás la vida parcheando, y cuando otro herede la base de datos que diseñaste te pitarán los oídos el resto de tu vida :)

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 3):

Un dato numérico, no se guarda con formato en la base de datos...
Ahora mismo dice que quieres guardar `114.239`, lo cuál es un error...
El tipo de dato a guardar es `INT`, y el valor de este es: `114239`, asi, sin comas, números, ni nada.

Al momento de querer mostrar el dato, es cuando le das un formato, por que de estos, existen muchos...
Es un número básico ? Es un numero con divisores decimales ? Es un numero con divisores de Miles ? Es un número que debe mostrar 2 decimales ?? etc.
Es decir, que para el mismo valor, puedes tener todos esos formatos (y quizás más):

- 114239
- 114.239
- 114.239,00
- 114239,00

Aún así, cada uno de ellos, es el mismo valor básico que guardas en la base de datos... el mismo 114239.

Comment: O podría directamente poner VARCHAR y poner el número con decimal, si lo que quiere obtener es el valor de por si

Comment: @AQMR ¿por qué recomiendas que si es `DECIMAL` lo declare como `VARCHAR` y no como `DECIMAL`? Es un gravísimo error declarar los tipos de datos como algo que no son. Luego hay que estar parcheando el código por todos lados, aparte de los posibles errores que esto puede provocar y los esfuerzos suplementarios para calculcar, comparar, etc.

Comment: Ah bueno, perdona, desconocía todo lo que podría conllevar. Aprendida la lección =3

Comment: @AQMR, no, simplemente no, ese no es el modo de guardar ese tipo de datos. No te crees problemas a futuro por ahorrarte unos minutos de programación ;)