# INSERT EN SQL CON CIFRAS CON COMAS Y DECIMALES

Tags: sql, insert

Como hago un insert en mi base de datos de una cifra con este formato? **12,050.00** en una columna pero que no sea de tipo varchar o text, tiene que ser un campo numerico

Comment: Los decimales son parte de un número pero el separador de miles no. No se puede guardar un separador de miles en un campo numérico.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Ayuda con tipo de dato en MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130609/ayuda-con-tipo-de-dato-en-mysql). Se recomienda un tipo de dato `DECIMAL` y olvidarte del separador de miles a la hora ingresar los valores. El separador es algo relativo al formato, el cual es contextual, y no debería existir nunca en los datos. Por poner un ejemplo: en unos lugares se usa el punto como separador de miles, en otros la coma. Si guardas un formato fijo, luego tendrás que extraer la coma, convertir, reemplazar, etc, y no te digo nada si debes comparar, sumar, etc.